# Obtaining a sessionFactory in hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I just created two small crud applications one is a web application and the other I am running from a main method.

I am confused about how the sessionFactory object is being obtained in both the applications.

In my web application in DAOImpl I am just injecting the sessionFactory object and doing

```
@Repository
public class ContactDaoImpl implements ContactDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void addContact(Contact contact) { 

        //save: Persist the given transient instance
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(contact);
    }
```

My Spring Application Context

```
<!-- <context:property-placeholder> XML element automatically registers a new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer 
    bean in the Spring Context. -->
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.contactmanager"/>

    <!-- enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager"/>

    <!-- View Resolver Configured -->
    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

<!-- Creating DataSource -->
<bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    </bean>




<!-- To persist the object to database, the instance of SessionFactory interface is created. 
SessionFactory is a singleton instance which implements Factory design pattern. 
SessionFactory loads hibernate.cfg.xml and with the help of TransactionFactory and ConnectionProvider 
implements all the configuration settings on a database. -->

<!-- Configuring SessionFactory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.contactmanager.model.Contact</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>             
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

<!-- Configuring Hibernate Transaction Manager -->
    <bean id="hibernateTransactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
```

But in the other application In which I don't use Spring I only use hibernate. I have to get the sessionFactory from annotationConfiguration then open the session and begin transaction.

```
AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

   Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

    session.beginTransaction();

    Stock stock = new Stock();

    stock.setStockCode("4715");
    stock.setStockName("GENM");

    session.save(stock);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Can anyone tell me why I do have to written more lines of code to persist an object here. Is the Spring configuration doing everything in the first application?

Comment: Yes, Spring is doing it for you in the webapp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of your Spring configuration is configuring the sessionFactory bean:

```
<!-- Configuring SessionFactory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.contactmanager.model.Contact</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>             
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

You can read more about setting up the Hibernate session factory with Spring [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#orm-session-factory-setup)

This part of your DAO code is responsible for asking Spring to inject the session factory:

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

You can read more about autowiring in Spring [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-autowire)